# Simple password check TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, sql

I'm getting this error and the highlighted code is 
**passW[0]**

What does this error mean exactly? It's a simple comparison but since its returned as a tuple i can't compare it. Do i need to change password into a tuple? or do i have to do the other way around for it come out as equal?
Here's my full code. It's a simple password check.

```
def check_login(db, useremail, password):
    """returns True if password matches stored"""

    cur = db.cursor()
    password1 = db.crypt(password)
    ur = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?"
    cur.execute(ur, (useremail,))
    user = cur.fetchone()
    if user[0] == useremail:
        pas = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?"
        cur.execute(pas, (useremail, password1,))
        passW = cur.fetchone()
        if passW[0] == password1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: The method `__getitem__` is called when you apply the `[]` operator on a variable. This error means, that `passW` is of type `None` and does not have the `__getitem__` method. I don't have any experience with databases, but I think, that passW could not be retrieved from the database.

Comment: You may also have the same problem with the `SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?` query. You could do the whole function with the single line `return db.cursor().query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?", (useremail, db.crypt(password))).fetchone() is not None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
passW = cur.fetchone()
```

[`cur.fetchone()`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) returns `None` when there in no match.  Since you're taking password from the user, and looking it up with that and the email, if the passwords don't match, you won't find the row.  As a result, `cur.fetchone()` returns None.  In fact, this:

```
passW = cur.fetchone()
if passW[0] == password1:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Can probably just turn into:

```
return if cur.fetchone() is not None:
    return True
return False
```

Or as Jen-Ya suggested:

```
return cur.fetchone() is not None
```

Comment: Even shorter:
`return cur.fechone() is not None`

Comment: Hehe, I don't know why I didn't do that.  Thanks!  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys Aya and your guys suggestion fixed it for me :D